Why use the word "event" in singular form in the following context?
I am trying to understand the following sentence:

In many cases, we are interested in the probability of some event, given that some other event has happened.


"some" + "event": Why did author decide to write in such a form?

P.S.: As far as I know "some" is used with plural forms not singular form.

Yes, it is when it means 'several', but here it means 'an event' - see Paul's answer.

Some has several different meanings. One is "several things" but another correct meaning is "one unknown thing" - it is kind of like the short version of "something" meaning an unknown thing.

"Something" is a contraction of "some thing" but it can't contract when an adjective is to be applied to the thing as in  "some other thing", or a different noun than "thing" is to be used.

Here some X means roughly “an unspecified X.” A few other examples of this usage are

I don’t know why I’ve been so tired. Maybe I’ve caught some bug.
When we left the restaurant, we saw some guy outside walking a squirrel on a leash.
Some day my prince will come.


I would add x: an unspecified X, to avoid people misreading it.

Done. Thanks @Lambie.
